# Mixed Asp / Asp.NET / ASP.NET MVC Site

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to set up so that my default page 
http://demo.liginsurance.com/  goes to 
http://demo.liginsurance.com/default.asp

currently it goes to http://demo.liginsurance.com/Home/Index

what route can i write or ignore  to get that to work...

-Thanks

Hurricane

Comment: Is there more to your question? You just configure the default document in IIS, that's all.

Comment: What about a simple non mvc re-direct?

Comment: IIS6 

Documents tab :  First item 
Default.asp

A redirect would show /default.asp   not my preferred outcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing that finally fixed it was :

routes.IgnoreRoute("");

Answer (score 1):

Read about Webforms routing [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/11/using-routing-with-webforms.aspx), this should help you with what you need.